# json result returns error

Tags: jquery

I have a json array

var states = { "1": "California", "2": "LA" };

How can i count and print the items in states. It should print 2.

if I use states.length it gives an error

Comment: That's an object, not an array, so there is no length. I'm not sure how you'd reference the '2' element, though, since it's a number. If you can reference the element in quotes (i.e. something like states["2"]) it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to count the members of an object you can do this:

```
for (val in states) {
    alert(states[val]);
    count++;
}
alert(count);
```

Comment: If you also want to print the states, you can add a line after "count++" to print the state name.

Answer (score 1):

Thats not an array.

```
var states = [ "California", "LA" ];
```